# UIButton doesn't display on UITableViewCell when the product is run

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, subview

[image: The storyboard image of the tableviewcontroller]

I've sought answers for this simple question for four hours all over the Internet and yet I am still lost. I am a beginner in Xcode which might explain all the confusion for me.

As you see from the image, I want to add a button in the tableview that directs to the home screen of my app. So I added an additional tableviewcell and put the following code into the tableviewcontroller.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if (indexPath.row == 0){

        let cell: UITableViewCell = HomeButtonTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default,
            reuseIdentifier: "LetsGoHome")
        return cell
    }

    else{
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("WordListTableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! WordListTableViewCell

        let row = indexPath.row - 1
        cell.formulaLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleHeadline)
        cell.formulaLabel.text = wordListObject.quizList[row]
        cell.formulaImage.image = UIImage(named: formulaImages[row])

        return cell
    }
}
```

Perhaps I'm not telling you enough about what I did, but what I know for sure is that (although most answers related to this question suggest doing this) `bringSubviewToFront` doesn't work no matter in what way I try it.

Please give suggestions as to what other area I could have made a mistake and if there's a better way for me to navigate from the tableview screen to my home screen. I would also like suggestions.

Comment: It is not good idea to put a UIButton inside UITableViewCell.
One of the purpose of UITableViewCell is ability to be selected. So just insert a label into the first prototype row and make sure you make a proper action in func didSelectRowAt:...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!
The only problem is that...I don't know why, but labels and UIViews that I include in the first prototype cell just don't appear at all, similar to the button. Using bringSubviewToFront or changing the z position doesn't help neither

Comment: Ok I understand. So what is definitely appearing in the row when built. Please provide a screenshot or link to your project.

Answer (score -2):

It would better to use a Navigation Controller for this.

[Storyboard example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omhRh.png)